# Nothing is working after database movement to another drive

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, database

I have dev environment with SQL and Sharepoint 2013 installed on same machine. My C drive was full so i moved "WSS Logging" data base to another drive. After movement none of my site collections are working apart from Central Admin.

I can not even create a new web application ans it throws following error:

> The file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\db.mdf" is compressed but
>   does not reside in a read-only database or filegroup. The file must be
>   decompressed. CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not
>   be created. Check related errors.

**EDIT**
I used below mentioned URL to move DB.
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52007/how-do-i-move-sql-server-database-files

Waqas's solution below worked for New application but i still can not access the existing site collection. I am getting below error:

*HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid*

Comment: How did you perform the database move onto the second drive? Have you checked the permissions applied to the folder(s) containing the mdf and ldf files?

Comment: I have added the details of how i moved the DB

Comment: Can you provide any further details of the errors? Can you turn off the call stack (CallStack="false") and custom errors (customErrors mode="Off") in the web application web.config file for one of the affected web applications and provide the output it should give?

Comment: 500.19 is usually related to malformed XML in the web.config file - do you have a backup of any of the web.config files that you could compare with the one that's currently on the machine?

Answer (score 1):

this error telling us, the new location is under compressed folder. In this situation, you have to `uncheck the Compress contents to save disk space.`

- Right Click on the Data Folder > click on Properties
- Under General Click on Advanced
- On this page make sure `Compress contents to save disk space is
  unchecked`

If it is uncheck, go to up folder( MSSQL10_50....) and so on.

[check this](https://sqlserver-help.com/2014/05/22/solution-the-file-mdf-is-compressed-but-does-not-reside-in-a-read-only-database-or-filegroup-the-file-must-be-decompressed/)

Comment: Thanks Waqas. Your suggestion worked for creating new applications, but i could not access the existing site collections yet

Comment: what error u are getting for the existing site collection? what are the status of Database in the central admin? may be need to clear the config cache...